# Target specific class in div for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to target only the classes "Front" and "Back" of the "Flip-tile" that I am currently hovering over. How do you solve this with javascript, currently it is toggling them all at the same time.

The HTML:

```
    <div class="flip-tile">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="project-tile primary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <img class="tile-img" src="../static/img/first.png">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Front side</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back" style="display:none;">
            <div class="project-tile secondary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Back side</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-tile">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="project-tile primary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <img class="tile-img" src="../static/img/first.png">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Front side</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back" style="display:none;">
            <div class="project-tile secondary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Backside</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(".flip-tile").hover(function() {
    $(".front").hide()
    $(".back").show()},
    function() {
    $(".back").hide()
    $(".front").show()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's so easy using `find()` on jQuery, but you can make it on easiest way with CSS.

### Javascript:

```
$(".flip-tile").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".front").hide();
    $(this).find(".back").show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find(".back").hide();
    $(this).find(".front").show();
  }
);
```

### CSS solution

```
.flip-title .front {
  display: block;
}
.flip-title .back {
  display: none;
}
.flip-title:hover .front {
  display: none;
}
.flip-title:hover .back {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).find(...)`.

```
$(".flip-tile").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".front").hide()
    $(this).find(".back").show()},
    function() {
    $(this).find(".back").hide()
    $(this).find(".front").show()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

I.e.

```
<script>
$( ".myclass.otherclass" ).css( "border", "13px solid red" );
</script>
```

The example will apply the border style to any .myclass.otherclass items along the HTML

good luck!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
$(".flip-tile").hover(function() {
     $(this).find(".front").hide()
     $(this).find(".back").show()},
    function() {
      $(this).find(".back").hide()
     $(this).find(".front").show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-tile">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="project-tile primary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <img class="tile-img" src="../static/img/first.png">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Front side</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back" style="display:none;">
            <div class="project-tile secondary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Back side</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-tile">
        <div class="front">
            <div class="project-tile primary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <img class="tile-img" src="../static/img/first.png">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Front side</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back" style="display:none;">
            <div class="project-tile secondary-color col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="tile-text">
                    <h4><span class="light">Backside</span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I must have been using the find() wrong when i tried a similar solution earlier!